# converting a column in json format into a new data frame

Tags: json, r

I have a **csv file** and one of the column is in **json format**.

that particular column in json format looks like this:

```
{"title":" ","body":" ","url":"thedailygreen print this healthy eating eat safe Dirty Dozen Foods page all"}
```

I have read this file using read.csv in R. Now, how to I create a new data frame from this column which should have field names as title, body and url.

Answer (score 6):

You can use package RJSONIO to parse the column values, e.g. :

```
library(RJSONIO)

# create an example data.frame with a json column
cell1 <- '{"title":"A","body":"X","url":"http://url1.x"}'
cell2 <- '{"title":"B","body":"Y","url":"http://url2.y"}'
cell3 <- '{"title":"C","body":"Z","url":"http://url3.z"}'

df <- data.frame(jsoncol = c(cell1,cell2,cell3),stringsAsFactors=F)

# parse json and create a data.frame
res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,
               lapply(df$jsoncol, FUN=function(x){ as.list(fromJSON(x))}))

> res
   title body           url
     A    X   http://url1.x
     B    Y   http://url2.y
     C    Z   http://url3.z
```

N.B. :
the code above assumes all the cells contains title, body and url only. If there can be other properties in the json cells, use this code instead :

```
vals <- lapply(df$jsoncol,fromJSON)
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(vals,FUN=function(v){ data.frame(title=v['title'],
                                                              body =v['body'],
                                                              url  =v['url']) }))
```

**EDIT (as per comment):**

I've read the file using the following code :

```
df <- read.table(file="c:\\sample.tsv", 
                 header=T, sep="\t", colClasses="character")
```

then parsed using this code :

```
# define a simple function to turn NULL to NA
naIfnull <- function(x){if(!is.null(x)) x else NA}

vals <- lapply(df$boilerplate,fromJSON)
res <- do.call(rbind, 
               lapply(vals,FUN=function(v){ v <- as.list(v)
                                            data.frame(title=naIfnull(v$title),
                                                       body =naIfnull(v$body),
                                                       url  =naIfnull(v$url)) }))
```

Comment: My code is"res <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,lapply(smpl$boilerplate, FUN=function(x){ as.list(fromJSON(x))}))" where smpl is my dataframe and boilerplate is the column which is in json format. But I got following error "Error in fromJSON(x) : 
  STRING_ELT() can only be applied to a 'character vector', not a 'integer'

Comment: @user3928988: sorry, I can't download from that link because I don't have an account. Can't you post a sample of your data.frame reproducing the problem ?

Comment: is there any way I could send the actual file to you. As there are many ways to read a file like read.csv and read.table. I believe the problem started with that

Comment: fileis in the following link:  http://ge.tt/8o9VAdr1/v/0?c                   Look for 3 column ,column name: boilerplate

Comment: I've tried to use the code above and I am constantly getting : Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or path to existing file. My text is : {"accuracy":41.394,"altitude":0.0,"bearing":0.0,"elapsedRealtimeNanos":306176061264038,"extras":null,"latitude":46.7941727,"longitude":23.6628978,"provider":"fused","speed":0.0,"time":1420711490869,"complete":true,"fromMockProvider":false}

Comment: `x <- fromJSON('{"accuracy":41.394,"altitude":0.0,"bearing":0.0,"elapsedRealtimeNanos":306176061264038,"extras":null,"latitude":46.7941727,"longitude":23.6628978,"provider":"fused","speed":0.0,"time":1420711490869,"complete":true,"fromMockProvider":false}')` works perfectly on my machine... maybe are you doing something different ?