# Handling large volume of json data present in column of csv file in R

Tags: json, r, csv, large-data

I have a csv file which has 10 millions of row. I have 4 column and one of this column contain json data. Now I have to convert the json data into the data frame. I found the following [feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382719/converting-a-column-in-json-format-into-a-new-data-frame) . and it is working fine for less no of row. but when I tried using the same function to read whole data it is not able to process it. not even for 50k rows.

My system: 64 bit 4 gb ram and 500 harddisk

Data:

```
    id,event,event_timestamp,properties
    a,x,2016-08-29 02:07:56.88,"{""email_id"": ""a@gmail.com"", ""timeStamp"": ""29-08-2016 07:43:10"", ""No Of Products"": 1, ""Cart Value"": ""1495""}"
    b,y,2016-08-29 03:04:00.08,"{""email_id"": ""b@gmail.com"", ""timeStamp"": ""29-08-2016 08:39:03"", ""No Of Products"": 4, ""Cart Value"": ""877""}"
    c,x,2016-08-29 00:26:23.213,"{""category"": ""dd"", ""timeStamp"": ""29-08-2016 06:00:27""}"
    d,x,2016-08-29 02:31:20.89,"{""timeStamp"": ""29-08-2016 08:05:40""}"
    e,x,2016-08-29 03:12:53.29,"{""search_query"": ""text str "", ""timeStamp"": ""29-08-2016 08:49:57""}"
```

Comment: which fields do you need to keep? it seems that your json column seems a random list of fields changing across rows.

Comment: You could do something like `library(tidyverse); df %>% mutate(properties = map(properties, ~as_data_frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(.x)))) %>% unnest()`, but it has a good chance of taking a while and turning a big data.frame into a huge data.frame as it adds as many columns as there are keys in the JSON, inserting `NA`s for the rest.